# group some records and Ignore some differences in grouping records in mysql (PROBLEM IN GROUPING)

Tags: mysql, database, group-by, timestamp, group-concat

I want to group my records by the time they are modified. (time means the minute)

A screenshot from my table:

[image: My Records in the 'main' table]

And the code is:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(text) as final_text 
  FROM main WHERE HSA = 'YES' 
 GROUP BY SUBSTRING(timestamps,1,16);
```

the result is:

[image: RESULT]

you can see that 4 of my records are modified at `12:23` , 4 of them at `12:35` and one of them at `12:36`.

But, I want mysql to group all records together if they are less than two minutes apart
(ignore differences less than 2 minutes!)

Please help me how to add my last record to the second group

Comment: What datatype is timestamps (it would help if you published your table definition)? Please add sample data and expected outcome as text which we can use as opposed to links which we can't (and are disinclined to). Please read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Confirm that you want to group all rows in 2 intervals and tell us the start datetime for this range grouping.

Comment: 'timestamps' row has timestamp datatype. In this example, I wanna 2 groups;
but my main problem is that for example I want 12:33 = 12:34 = 12:35 = 12:32 = 12:31.

I have 3 records at 12:35 and one record at 12:36 and I want them to be in one group but they are in 2 groups.
I want mysql to ignore 2 minutes difference between timestamps and if there are some records that has timestamps with less than 2 minutes diversity, I want them to be in one group!

Comment: Take a look at your `SUBSTRING(timestamps, 1,16)` function at what it's doing https://dbfiddle.uk/eh2qNRAn

Comment: SUBSTRING(timestamps, 1,16) returns : yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm.
What then?